# In Python how can I convert list ['a,b'] into ['a','b']

Tags: python, list

In Python how can I convert  list `['a.com, b.com']` into `['a.com','b.com']`. I am using exec function to execute a Python script where I need to send email to multiple people when I send the list as argument using exec command, argument value comes as a list with single quote around all the names `['a.com, b.com']` where as I want them as list of separate names `['a.com','b.com']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all values are separated with `', '`, you can use split.

```py
list = ['a.com, b.com']
new_list = list[0].split(', ')
print(new_list) 
# ['a.com', 'b.com']
```